# Guardar texto TextFiel em uma variável e inseir em um campo usando Selenium driver

Tags: javafx, selenium-webdriver

Preciso pegar dados de um Textfiel (letras e número) e depois inserir em um campo usando o Selenium.

```
//Classe1 para pegar texto
String guardarPlaca;
    @FXML
    public void inserirDados(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        guardarPlaca = fieldPlaca.getText();
//pega o valor dele, e armazena na variável guardarplaca
        System.out.println(guardarPlaca);

    }


//Classe 2 para inserir em em campo usando Selenium
    Classe1 guardarPlaca = new Classe1();        
    driver.findElement(By.id("placa")).getAttribute("value");
    WebElement placa = driver.findElement(By.id("placa"));// localiza campo
    placa.clear();
    placa.sendKeys(String.valueOf(guardarPlaca));
```

Comment: Qual o erro que está dando? Quando você declara o campo fieldPlaca a declaração dele é precedida por @FXML?

Comment: Consegui resolver
muito simples declarar a variável como public static String

Comment: Nesse caso você pode responder sua própria pergunta, assim ajudará outras pessoas com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Resolvi assim
//declarar a variável
public static String guardarPlaca;

//pega o valor os valores do textfiel e armazenar nas variaveis
  guardarPlaca = fieldPlaca.getText();
  System.out.println(guardarPlaca);

Comment: Resolvi assim
public static String guardarPlaca; //declarar a variável na classe 1
//pegar os valores do textfiel e armazenar nas variaveis
guardarPlaca = fieldPlaca.getText();
Classe 2
//chama variavel de outra classe
HmlController classe = new HmlController();
//cria uma nova variavel para essa classe
String placa = HmlController.guardarPlaca;
//metodo para inserir placa do textfiel no campo do site 
WebElement placadispositivo = driver.findElement(By.id("placa"));
placadispositivo.clear();
placadispositivo.sendKeys(String.valueOf(placa));//insere no campo

Comment: Reponda no campo abaixo e clique em "publicar sua resposta", essa parte é só para os comentários ^^